# Python is not writing to a file for some reason

Tags: python, file-io

Is there a reason why this is code is not writing to a file.  Everything else works on this except for the writing part I know I need to close the file but I'm not sure how?

```
import os
import sys
import csv
import pysftp as sftp

with open('c:/Python27/log_07032014_1512.txt','r') as inf,    
open('C:/Python27/Errors.txt','w')as outf:
reader = csv.reader(inf)
writer = csv.writer(outf)
for line in inf:
    if 'Error' in line:
        print line

def sftpExample():
try:
    s = sftp.Connection('***.***.***.***', username = '******', password = '****')
    remotepath ='/home/*****/BOA.txt'
    localpath = 'C:/Python27/Errors.txt'
    s.put(localpath,remotepath)

    s.close()
except Exception, e:
    print str(e)

sftpExample()
```

Comment: Could you fix the indentation of your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, I don't see you writing to the file:

```
for line in inf:
    if 'Error' in line:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

If you want to check if any particular "column" contains error, as  Jon Clements suggests below, you should loop over the csv reader output not over the raw file:

```
for line in reader:
        if 'Error' in line:
            writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: While I agree with you that there's never anything actually trying to write to the output stream, it's arguable that perhaps it's a genuine test using `csv.reader` to check if any *column* of the processed line contains `Error` rather than a simple substring check of the raw line itself.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll adjust my comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not sure I have understood correctly, but:

- You dont seem to be indenting correctly. `inf` and `outf` are open files only within `with` context:

  ```
  with open('c:/Python27/log_07032014_1512.txt','r') as inf, open('C:/Python27/Errors.txt','w')as outf:
      print 'the files are open in this context'
  print 'the files are now closed'
  ```

You don't have to close the file.

- You don't seem to be writting to the output file.

I can't understand which are file format being used, so if they are text files, you should:

```
    with open('c:/Python27/log_07032014_1512.txt','r') as inf, open('C:/Python27/Errors.txt','w')as outf:
        for line in inf:
            if 'Error' in line:
                outf.write(line)
```

If they are csvs:

```
    with open('c:/Python27/log_07032014_1512.txt','r') as inf, open('C:/Python27/Errors.txt','w')as outf:
        reader = csv.reader(inf)
        writer = csv.writer(outf)
        for line in reader:
            if 'Error' in line:
                writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: I actually have it printing out correctly I need it to write to the new file. It's actually a txt file

Comment: So the second block of code in my answer is what you need. You can remove the reader and the writer, as they are not being used by your code. The only thing missing was that you were printing the line (`print line`) instead of writing it to the file (`outf.write(line)`)